# Disable Lightbox in responsive design

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I've searched previous SO posts regarding jQuery and responsive design but had no luck finding  anything similar.  My issue is, I have a website that when it hits > 960px it drops all the eye candy and becomes fluid.  On some pages I use lightbox to preview a larger image off of a thumbnail.  When the 960px is hit I would like to drop the lightbox effect.  Here is how I lightbox set up:

lightbox:

```
<a href="images/some-img.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="some title">some text &raquo;</a>
```

Is there way to say disable rel="lightbox" with jQuery at > 960px?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you only want the lightbox at smaller screen widths?  I've usually done the opposite, since lighboxes don't play nice with mobile.

Comment: No your right, it doesn't play well at all.  It's a typo... <

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use js for this. Depending on what lightbox library you are using you may need to reinitialize it after the lightbox `rel` property is added back.

```
var lightboxOnResize = function lightboxOnResize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $('a[rel="lightbox"]')
            .removeProp('rel')
            .addClass('lightboxRemoved');
    } else {
        $('a.lightboxRemoved').prop('rel', 'lightbox');
    }
}

$(document).ready(lightboxOnResize);
$(window).resize(lightboxOnResize);
```

Comment: This should do the trick @ryan I appreciate it.  I'm gonna grind away at it after lunch, thanks man.  (PS lovin this weather? Im from PA too)

Comment: Removing the property does not work in our environment :( debugging at the moment to find the root cause. Maybe removing info such as an item from ``Lightbox.imageArray``.

Comment: Added another solution as in our case Lightbox was initialised before and removing the ``rel`` property did not help. What you have to do in this case is to unbind the ``click`` event set through jQuery and voilà!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:  This code is untested, and will only remove the `rel="lightbox"`, not add it back in on resize.  Should be easy enough to add that in if its important to you.

```
var responsiveLightbox = function () {
   var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
   if (viewportWidth > 960){
       $('[rel=lightbox]').attr('rel', '');
   }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    responsiveLightbox();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    responsiveLightbox();
});
```

Comment: This won't deal with the window being resized larger again

Comment: as noted at the top of my response.  Generally with responsive design, I don't get too worked up worrying about the use case of people resizing the window back and forth.  That said, your code is better.

Answer (score 0):

This is coding approach.

You need to put a condition while you are hooking up lighbox to div.

Condition would be something like

if(screenPixel>960)
{
 Add my lightbox to the div
}

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers worked for me to remove Lightbox from a particular element, so I'm posting another solution that could help someone that is currently experiencing a similar issue.

My version of Lightbox2 calls an `initList` function which binds `click` functions and based on what elements have been "tagged" in the DOM for use by Lightbox calls then the `start` function. If you want to disable Lightbox for a particular element for a particular screen size than unbinding the click event could work.

**Be careful though with unbinding as there might be other scripts that have click behaviours attached to the element! If you store handlers in a variable you can later reference the behaviour like so `unbind('click', handler)`. Unfortunately, my version of Lightbox2 was not setup in that way, and as far as I can see, version [2.8.2 on Github](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/releases/tag/v2.8.2) does not have an unbind function nor a global reference handler variable. So in this context you would have to adapt the codebase when there are other click events attached that you need to keep.**

In any case, the code would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (screen.width < 1024) {
    $('#some-id').unbind('click');
  }
});
```

You don't even have to remove the `rel` property in the `a` element:

```
<a href="./linkedcontenturl.ext" id="some-id" rel="lightframe" target="_blank">click here!</a>
```

Depending on the content you are linking to (PDF for instance) it might be a good idea to add `target="_blank"` as well, but important is to test the experience first on the target set of devices, different devices could show different behaviours.