# Hide lightbox in tablet and mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am using the featherlight lightbox and need for it not to appear on tablet or mobile devices. I tried using the code from [Disable Lightbox in responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055352/disable-lightbox-in-responsive-design) but was unable to get this to work. Here is the code:

```js
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  
var lightbox = '<a href="http://info.ccfa.org/teamchallengetmm?&primary_source_code__c=internet&source_code_detail_1__c=ccteamchallenge.org&source_code_other__c=nottoolate_lightbox&which_event_are_you_interested_in__c=unknown&utm_source=tc_website&utm_medium=sitelink&utm_campaign=summer17&utm_content=nottoolate_lightbox&i_am_interested_in_=undecided"><img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/Summer17-Not-Too-Late-Lightbox-TC-Website.png "></a>';


function startLightbox(){
  $.featherlight(lightbox);
}

console.log(getCookie("tc_lightbox"));
if(getCookie("tc_lightbox")){
}
else{
  setCookie("tc_lightbox", 1);
  setTimeout(startLightbox, 1500);
}


function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}



});
```

```css
.featherlight-content h1,h3{
  margin:0;
}
.featherlight-content h1{
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.featherlight-content form input[type="text"], .featherlight-content form input[type="email"]{
    width:100%;
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px #757576 solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'avenirroman';
    color: #999;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.featherlight-content form input[type="submit"]{
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: #f37736;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'avenirblack', Arial Black;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
}

.featherlight .featherlight-content {
    background: transparent !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.featherlight img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

ive also tried

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $(lightbox).hide();
    }
```

and using display: none in a media query using css

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $(lightbox).hide();
}
```

Is just that the lightbox variable is referencing a string of text instead of an element. Checking the featherlight demo listed on their page, you could try something like this

```
$('a[data-featherlight]').hide();
```

If that doesn't work, you could also try adding a class to your lightbox string

```
var lightbox = '<a class="hidethis" href="http://info.ccfa.org/teamchallengetmm?&primary_source_code__c=internet&source_code_detail_1__c=ccteamchallenge.org&source_code_other__c=nottoolate_lightbox&which_event_are_you_interested_in__c=unknown&utm_source=tc_website&utm_medium=sitelink&utm_campaign=summer17&utm_content=nottoolate_lightbox&i_am_interested_in_=undecided"><img src="../images/content/pagebuilder/Summer17-Not-Too-Late-Lightbox-TC-Website.png "></a>';
```

and then use this line

```
$('.hidethis').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to *hide* it on small screens, but to **never load it** *unless it satisfies your requirements*. You could test for touch with Modernizr or some other check for screenSize. If the test doesn't pass... then you don't load the plugin.

```
if ( shouldWeShowLightbox ) {
  lightbox.init();
else {
  // don't do anything.. or possibly inject link HREFS or something different to deal with your situation
}
```

You can also periodically check what the screensize is and load the plugin it the screen gets bigger or something. Most quality plugins have a .destroy() method to kill it if for some reason you leave that 'view' or the requirement isn't met.

Comment: This is probably a key example in a book like this: https://abookapart.com/products/responsible-responsive-design

Comment: Often - you don't really have a choice... because you are working with limitations and people don't care... BUT ideally... you wouldn't even get the plugin code into your build in the first place - and instead, load it after the page has loaded... - so there are many degrees you can take this - as far as seriousness... Generally - with, a lightbox for example... I bundle it in - but only call it if it's big enough to actually be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable featherlight on a mobile or tablet add this jQuery script somewhere and it works perfectly for my case!

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   if (jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
       jQuery("a[data-featherlight]").attr('href', '').css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'pointer-events' : 'none'});
   }
});
</script>
```

Where 960 is the responsive breakpoint (960pixels) where you want to disable the lightbox effect.

We are force disabling all the a links that has the data-featherlight attribute